# Print lines with minimal values in multiple columns based on duplicated string in a third column

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to filter out lines with a non-unique string in a specific column while only retaining those lines that have minimal values in 2 other columns and of course those lines that have no duplicates. Please see my example table:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  1     BBBB
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  3     AAAA
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  3     BBBB
blah  blah  2     blah  blah  0     AAAA
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  0     AAAA
blah  blah  8     blah  blah  3     CCCC
```

Col1, Col2, Col4 and Col5 are not important and should just be copied. If a string in Col7 occurs more than once, out of all occurences I only want to print the line that has the **lowest value in Col3** and following that ,**if there is a tie**, the **lowest value in Col6**. In the end I would like to add a new column which says either "unique" or "multi" specifying if there was a duplicate or not.

My desired output would be something like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  0     AAAA  multi
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  1     BBBB  multi
blah  blah  8     blah  blah  3     CCCC  unique
```

So far I tried my best with awk. I can find all lines with duplicate strings with something like this and print them in one line but I don't know how to filter it before printing.

```
 awk '{dup[$7]=dup[$7] ? dup[$7] " duplicate of " $1 : $1} END {for (x in dup) print dup[x], x}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and solutions in awk (with explanations please) would be preferred since I'm trying to understand it better.

*Edited for better understanding.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`

**One-liner**

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $0,"Col8";next}function cp(){a[$7]=$0;b[$7]=$3;c[$7]=$6}{f=$7 in a;  d[$7]++}!f{o[++i]=$7; cp(); next}f && b[$7]>$3{cp();next}f && b[$7]==$3 && $6<c[$7]{cp();next}END{for(i=1; i in o; i++)print a[o[i]],(d[o[i]]>1?"multi":"unique")}' file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '
      # if first line was read then print current record and extra field as header
      # go to next line
      FNR==1{
             print $0,"Col8";
             next
      }
      # function which will be used frequently to store data
      function cp(){
             a[$7]=$0;
             b[$7]=$3;
             c[$7]=$6;
       }
       # variable f holds boolean status whether array a has key of field7 value
       # variable f will be used frequently  
       {
             f=$7 in a;
             d[$7]++
       }

       # if key does not exist in array a then
       !f{
             # store order
             # copy data
             # go to next line
             o[++i]=$7;
             cp();
             next
       }

       # if f is true and 3rd field value of previously stored data
       # is greater than current record field3 data then
       # we got smaller value lets save it
       # and go to next line

       f && b[$7]>$3{
              cp();
              next
       }

       # if variable f is true and field3 value of previously stored data
       # is equal to current record field3 its tie, 
       # and check whether 6th field value is lesser than previously stored value
       # then we got smaller value from field6 of current row/record/line
       # copy data
       # go to next line

       f && b[$7]==$3 && $6<c[$7]{
              cp();
              next
       }

       # end block
       # loop through array o,
       # print value from array a, where index being o[i]
       # d[o[i]] holds count of occurrence of field7
       # if its greater than 1 then its multi otherwise unique

    END{
            for(i=1; i in o; i++)
                 print a[o[i]],(d[o[i]]>1?"multi":"unique")
       }
      ' file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  3     AAAA
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  3     BBBB
blah  blah  2     blah  blah  0     AAAA
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  0     AAAA
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  1     BBBB
blah  blah  8     blah  blah  3     CCCC
```

Execution

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print $0,"Col8";next}function cp(){a[$7]=$0;b[$7]=$3;c[$7]=$6;{f=$7 in a;  d[$7]++}!f{o[++i]=$7;cp();next}f && b[$7]>$3{cp();next}f && b[$7]==$3 && $6<c[$7]{cp();next}END{for(i=1; i in o; i++)print a[o[i]],(d[o[i]]>1?"multi":"unique")}' file
```

**Output**

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7 Col8
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  0     AAAA multi
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  1     BBBB multi
blah  blah  8     blah  blah  3     CCCC unique
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! The explanations are very much appreciated. I will gladly accept this as my answer.

Comment: I found a mistake when the first occurence of a duplicate is actually the line with the minimal occuring values. In this case your solution will print it as a unique instead of a multi. I changed the example table accordingly. Sorry it took me a while to find this mistake. If you run it now, it will choose the right line for BBBB but it will flag it as unique.

Comment: @Skoddo: thanks for reporting, fixed issue moved `d[$7]++` outside function

Comment: Great. Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

**sort** + **uniq** + **sed** trick:

```
echo "$(head -1 file)  Col8" && \
      sort -k7 -k3,3 -k6,6 <(tail -n +2 file) | uniq -cf6 \
      | sed -E 's/^ *1 (.*)/\1  unique/; s/^ *([2-9]|[0-9]{2,}) (.*)/\2  multi/'
```

The output:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  0     AAAA  multi
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  1     BBBB  multi
blah  blah  8     blah  blah  3     CCCC  unique
```

**----------**

***Bonus*** solution with GNU ***datamash*** + **awk**:

```
datamash -WHfs -g7 count 7 min 6 min 3 <file \
    | awk 'NR==1{ $8="Col8" }NR>1{ $3=$10; $6=$9; $8=($8>1)?"multi":"unique" }{$9=$10=""}1' \
    | column -t
```

Comment: You are a magician with datamash, you are awesome with it :). Though I spent some time to write my single awk, this looks more easy with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue! with the help of other tools

```
$ head -1 file && sed 1d file | 
       sort -k7 -k3,3n -k6,6n | 
       uniq -c -f6 | 
       awk '!a[$NF]++{c=$1; gsub(" +"$1" +",""); print $0,c==1?"uniq":"multi"}'

Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
blah  blah  0     blah  blah  0     AAAA multi
blah  blah  1     blah  blah  1     BBBB multi
blah  blah  8     blah  blah  3     CCCC uniq
```

of course if your header is not really there you can get rid of the first part